# Lightroom SQLite database binary XMP format

Tags: sqlite, reverse-engineering, xmp, lightroom

Lightroom catalog is a SQLite database. Some of the metadata values are stored under `Adobe_AdditionalMetadata.XMP` column which is a BLOB data type.

When I save this blob, it is some binary file that I have no idea how to convert to/from an editable form.

According to the [documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform), xmp file has XML format

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ug08_ymk2VNAjElf0WWTa1BGV_iV-kJj/view?usp=sharing) is the example of such blob from my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was advised on the Lightroom forums, such columns use non-standard SQLite compress module.

Here is the link to the SQLite Windows binaries recompiled with non-standard compress module: https://github.com/mnaoumov/sqlite-lightroom-compress-fix

It can extract the xmp properties

```
select uncompress(xmp) from Adobe_AdditionalMetadata where id_local = 4539794;
```

But cannot write it back yet.

```
update Adobe_AdditionalMetadata
set xmp = compress('some valid xmp string value')
where id_local = 4539794;
```

It executes successfully but you won't be able to read it back with `uncompress()` function.

That's because the library from the link above fixes only `uncompress()` function. I am working to fix the `compress()` function as well

Comment: Make sure that `won't be able to read it back` is not a result of `'some string value'` not being valid XMP. Also `non-standard compress` is asking for trouble once others want to read your database: they might be unable to use foreign binaries or Windows.

Comment: @AmigoJack obviously I tied proper xmp without success. And non-standard compress is not my choice, that's how Lightroom works internally

Comment: Then your example code is incorrect and will still trigger further questions, such as if `SELECT compress( uncompress( xmp ) )= xmp` is TRUE or not.

Comment: @AmigoJack thanks, modified code sample for more clarity

Comment: It's worse than before: now it contradicts to your own answer - you already know how to decode the BLOB: by using `uncompress()`. Wasn't your actual problem that `compress()` might be working differently than expected?

Comment: @AmigoJack yes, the real problem is that the Lightroom database decided to use their own compress/uncompress implementation. I found a library that reverse-engineered the `uncompress()` function, but not `compress()`, so that's why I need to implement it by myself

Comment: Why is everyone referring to this compiled code without referencing the modifications or the source to compile it????

Comment: @Asher if you need it for some reason, I can prepare a commit with changes on GitHub

Comment: FYI, the change is (in zlib-compressed strings) "Rather than store a variable-length integer of 1-5
bytes containing the length of the original uncompressed string, Lightroom
stores 4 bytes, MSB to LSB"